# Can i link to other websites in my newsletter?

Tags: links, content, copyright, legal, newsletter

I'm intrested in adding several intresting articles on my newsletter from other websites.

Am i allowed to do that in general or every website has it's own rules?

Comment: By "adding several intresting articles from other websites", are you talking about linking to those websites, or are you talking about copying and pasting the entire articles from that website into your newsletter. If you're copying and pasting, then you could run into copyright troubles, but if you're just providing links (and perhaps excerpts), then you should be fine.

Comment: i meant linking...

Comment: @Christofian it's not illegal it can be considered Fair Use, http://www.copyright.gov/fls/fl102.html please don't spread false rumors.

Comment: @Anagio: I don't see how the reproduction of entire articles for financial gain can be considered "Fair Use"?! Although it seems the OP is only linking to said articles, so it's a moot point.

Comment: @w3d who said anything about financial gain? They want to link to articles, that's not illegal, nor is copying an entire article and pasting it on a website. You can't pass the article off as your own if you're trying to make money from that article. Google news links to http://www.washingtonpost.com/business/economy/home-prices-rose-again-in-september/2012/11/27/ab125b3a-3890-11e2-b01f-5f55b193f58f_story.html copy and paste the first paragraph begnning with "Home prices continued to rise..." in Google Search and you'll see tons of news sites copying the same article.

Comment: @Anagio nothings wrong with copying the first paragraph of the article and providing a link. What me and w3d are talking about is people copying entire articles, or copying significant portions of articles but failing to provide your own analysis/original work. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Even an entire article copied isn't illegal under fair use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see how this could be a problem, unless you are writing bad things about such websites and linking to them, everybody would like new traffic.

Now, if you are in fact writing not so good things, then it could be a problem and you could be held accountable for what you said.

Comment: And if i earn money from it could they claim something because of it? or if they decide not to allow me do it for some reason they can only ask me not to do it right?

Comment: Well it depends in which way are you earning money. I don't know exactly what you mean, (please clarify for a better answer) but if you have google adsense for example running on your website, you are earning money by generating traffic to those websites via adsense, perfectly legal.

Answer (score 0):

They should be happy for incoming traffic.

Comment: And if i earn money from it could they claim something because of it? or if they decide not to allow me do it for some reason they can only ask me not to do it right?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you're safe.

Most websites have rules regarding:

- hot linking images
- stealing/borrowing their images
- stealing/borrowing their content

But linking to their website in general, regardless if you are earning a referral fee or not, is not breaking any laws to my knowledge.